# YUI 3: How to get native DOM element wrapped inside Node?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

I've used this simple technique to get a native DOM element in jQuery:

```
var el = $('#myid');
var native = el[0];  //or el.get(0);
```

How can I do this in YUI 3? For example, I want to use `getElementsByName` DOM method, which is not supported by YUI 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var el = Y.one("#myid");
var native = el.getDOMNode();
```

If you can't be confident that '#myid' is in the DOM then you should check for null first. YUI's .one doesn't chain like in jQuery.

```
var el = Y.one("#myid"), native;
if (el !== null) {
    native = el.getDOMNode();
}
```